# AngularJS not working on some computer

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs, tomcat

I have angularjs java web-app and on my local computer work perfect , ng-table and everything. I use GoogleChrome .

Problem is, when I put app on another computer , NG-table not show my data . I use also Chrome and same war.

This is code where reload ng-table and I get data in value but they not show. Have someone idea what is problem, I think something with browser becose same war and same code not work same and get identical data.

```
     $scope.$watch(function () { return commonFactory.getList();  }, function (value) {
     if( value!=undefined && value[0]!=undefined){
         var r = value[0].countNgTable;
     }
     var initialParams = {
                count: r
            };
            var initialSettings = {
                // page size buttons (right set of buttons in demo)
                counts: [10,25,50,100,1000],
                // determines the pager buttons (left set of buttons in demo)
                paginationMaxBlocks: 23,
                paginationMinBlocks: 2,
                dataset:angular.copy(value)
            };

     self.tableParams =  new ngTableParams(initialParams, initialSettings);
     self.tableParams.match=function(t){
         commonFactory.setCounter(t)
        }
 });
```

Comment: did you do npm install after putting your code in another machine?
This is surely a case of missing configuration

Comment: No, I didn'tnpm install and I don't know what is it, I will looking on google. But it's strangely becose everything else work and have a lot of code. Only ng-table not working, have grid with column but not rows with data

Comment: One thing you can try to make sure if this is the issue - Rather than getting the data from java code hardcode the data that works exactly in the working machine and check if it works. Also please check if their is any error in console

Comment: Ok, I try and check. Only I know that no have error in console. Thank you and I write if will works.